# Using Prepared Statement multiple times efficiently

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

Below is the code which I am using to insert `multiple records( around 5000-7000)` in the Oracle Database using Prepared Statement.

The way I am doing currently is good? Or it can be improve more using some `batch thing`?

```
pstatement = db_connection.prepareStatement(PDSLnPConstants.UPSERT_SQL);

for (Entry<Integer, LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>> entry : MAPPING.entrySet()) {

    pstatement.setInt(1, entry.getKey());
    pstatement.setString(2, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.CGUID_ID));
    pstatement.setString(3, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.PGUID_ID));
    pstatement.setString(4, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.SGUID_ID));
    pstatement.setString(5, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.UID_ID));
    pstatement.setString(6, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.ULOC_ID));
    pstatement.setString(7, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.SLOC_ID));
    pstatement.setString(8, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.PLOC_ID));
    pstatement.setString(9, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.ALOC_ID));
    pstatement.setString(10, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.SITE_ID));
    pstatement.executeUpdate();

    pstatement.clearParameters();
}
```

**Udpated Code That I am Using:-**

```
public void runNextCommand() {

    Connection db_connection = null;
    PreparedStatement pstatement = null;
    int batchLimit = 1000;
    boolean autoCommit = false;

    try {
        db_connection = getDBConnection();

        autoCommit = db_connection.getAutoCommit();
        db_connection.setAutoCommit(false); //Turn off autoCommit
        pstatement = db_connection.prepareStatement(LnPConstants.UPSERT_SQL); // create a statement

        for (Entry<Integer, LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>> entry : GUID_ID_MAPPING.entrySet()) {
            pstatement.setInt(1, entry.getKey());
            pstatement.setString(2, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.CGUID_ID));
            pstatement.setString(3, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.PGUID_ID));
            pstatement.setString(4, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.SGUID_ID));
            pstatement.setString(5, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.UID_ID));
            pstatement.setString(6, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.ULOC_ID));
            pstatement.setString(7, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.SLOC_ID));
            pstatement.setString(8, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.PLOC_ID));
            pstatement.setString(9, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.ALOC_ID));
            pstatement.setString(10, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.SITE_ID));
            pstatement.addBatch();

            batchLimit--;

            if(batchLimit == 0){
                pstatement.executeBatch();
                pstatement.clearBatch();
                batchLimit = 1000;
            }
            pstatement.clearParameters();
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        getLogger().log(LogLevel.ERROR, e);
    } finally {
        try {
            pstatement.executeBatch();
            db_connection.commit();
            db_connection.setAutoCommit(autoCommit);
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            getLogger().log(LogLevel.ERROR, e1.getMessage(), e1.fillInStackTrace());
        }

        if (pstatement  != null) {
            try {
                pstatement.close();
                pstatement = null;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                getLogger().log(LogLevel.ERROR, e.getMessage(), e.fillInStackTrace());
            }
        }
        if (db_connection!= null) {
            try {
                db_connection.close();
                db_connection = null;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                getLogger().log(LogLevel.ERROR, e.getMessage(), e.fillInStackTrace());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (Make sure transactions are being used correctly. Otherwise the posted code "will not be good", even [re-]using prepared statements. That is, INSERT/UPDATE is "fast". COMMIT is "slow".)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can think of using [`addBatch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch%28%29) and executing a back of statements in one shot. Also, as @pst commented in your question, consider using `trasaction`.

The way you would do is as follows:

```
boolean autoCommit = connection.getAutoCommit();
try{
    connection.setAutoCommit(false //Turn off autoCommit
    pstatement = db_connection.prepareStatement(PDSLnPConstants.UPSERT_SQL);

    int batchLimit = 1000;

    try{
        for (Entry<Integer, LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>> entry : MAPPING.entrySet()) {
            pstatement.setInt(1, entry.getKey());
            pstatement.setString(2, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.CGUID_ID));
            pstatement.setString(3, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.PGUID_ID));
            pstatement.setString(4, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.SGUID_ID));
            pstatement.setString(5, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.UID_ID));
            pstatement.setString(6, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.ULOC_ID));
            pstatement.setString(7, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.SLOC_ID));
            pstatement.setString(8, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.PLOC_ID));
            pstatement.setString(9, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.ALOC_ID));
            pstatement.setString(10, entry.getValue().get(LnPConstants.SITE_ID));
            
            pstatement.addBatch();
            batchLimit--;
            
            if(batchLimit == 0){
                pstatement.executeBatch();
                pstatement.clearBatch();
                batchLimit = 1000;
            }
             pstatement.clearParameters();
        }
    }finally{
        //for the remaining ones
        pstatement.executeBatch();
        
        //commit your updates
        connection.commit();
    }
}finally{
    connection.setAutoCommit(autoCommit);
}
```

The idea is to set a limit for batch updates and execute a database update only when you reach a particular limit. This way you're limiting a database call to once every `batchLimit` that you've defined. This way it would be faster.

Also note for the `transaction`, I've just shown how and when to `commit`. This might not always be the correct point to `commit` because this decision would be based on your requirement. You might also want to perform a `rollback` in case of an exception. So it's upto you to decide.

Have a look at ["Using Transaction"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html) tutorial to get a better picture of how to use `transaction`.

Comment: Can you provide me an example basis on my code so that I get clear picture how to use `addBatch()` here? It will be of great help.

Comment: @Nevzz03: Updated my answer with a sample code. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks Sujay for the detailed answer. Appreciated your help. I just updated my question with the full code that I am using currently as suggested by you after making changes. Can yout take a look and let me know if everything looks good to you and I am not doing anything wrong?

Comment: @Nevzz03: Well in case you encounter a `SQLException` when you're trying to perform a database update, you might consider a `rollback`. Also, I had set the `batchLimit` as 1000 which you can obviously tune based on your requirement. Other than that I think your code looks fine enough to me :)

Comment: Oh and you forgot to reset your `autoCommit` to its initial value. Take care of that as well

Comment: I did that right? In my finally block? `finally { try { pstatement.executeBatch(); db_connection.commit(); db_connection.setAutoCommit(autoCommit); }`

Comment: @Nevzz03: sorry, i missed that! if you found this helpful, do consider accepting this as an answer :)

Comment: @Nevzz03: you are also missing a `batchLimit--;` statement

Comment: what can i do if further executions depend on "ps.getUpdateCount()" ?

Answer (score 1):

Your piece of code seems good to me.

Just for code cleanness, I'd put `entry.getValue()` into a variable (call it `value`).
And there's no need to call `clearParameters()`.

Last, remember to correctly dispose the prepared statement when you don't need it anymore (`close()`).

Comment: Thanks gd1 for the suggestions. Why do you think there's no need to call `clearParameters()`? I just wanted to know from the knowledge point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, doing batch updates would significantly improve your performance. Just google for it, my preferred answer is [this one from Mkyong.com](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/). Else, your code looks ok. "clearParameters()" is not really necessary, it might even consume some processor cycles. Important: if AutoCommit was enabled, don't forget to disable it before, and enable it after doing the updates, this brings again a tremendous improvement.

PS

Above recommendation is based also on my experience. I've just noted that this question was already asked [here at Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892105/bulk-insert-in-java-using-prepared-statements-batch-update) and the answer is very detailed. More on PreparedStatements and batches can be found in the Oracle docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/preparedstatement.html) and about Transactions (AutoCommit) [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html).