# Insert multiple rows in Sql Server Tables using java

Tags: java, database, sql-server-2008, jdbc, sql-insert

Hi i want to achieve following

```
insert into t1 (c1,c2) values (v1,v2)
```

above transaction will create a unique identifier for the row created. lets say UIDT1

now i want to execute multiple inserts in another table like

```
insert into t2 (c1,c2,c3) values (UIDT1,v2,v3)
insert into t2 (c1,c2,c3) values (UIDT1,v2,v3)
insert into t2 (c1,c2,c3) values (UIDT1,v2,v3)
.
.
.
```

using Java, i can write all queries in a text file and read one by one and create all transactions but i wanted to know if there is any more efficient way of doing the same.
Need your inputs..

Note : I am using Spring JDBC

Purpose : Unit testing, creating User(t1) and UserDetails(t2) considering tests run with a fresh DB i am creating users and user details first and then using that user i will test other scenarios.

Comment: i am using spring jdbc

Comment: For executing multiple inserts you could look into using a PreparedStatement with batches. A little more info here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892105/bulk-insert-in-java-using-prepared-statements-batch-update

Answer (score 0):

You can do somthing like this

```
String [] queries = {
    "insert into t2 (c1,c2,c3) values (UIDT1,v2,v3)",
    "insert into t2 (c1,c2,c3) values (UIDT1,v2,v3)",
    "insert into t2 (c1,c2,c3) values (UIDT1,v2,v3)"
};
try{
connectionObject.setAutoCommit(false);
Statement statement = connectionObject.createStatement();

for (String query : queries) {
    statement.addBatch(query);
}
statement.executeBatch();
connectionObject.commit();
}
catch(SQLException e){
e.printStackTrace(); 
}
finally{
//closing statements 
}
```