# java preparedStatement.executeUpdate() only insert the last row

Tags: java, sql, insert

This is my code:

```
String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Links(PageId, LinkId) values(?, ?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
Vector<String> links = page.getLinks();    
for (String string : links) {       
    Concept c = dbpedia.findConceptbyTitle(string);                     
    if (c != null) {
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(page.getID()));
        preparedStatement.setInt(2, c.id);
    }    
}
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Strangely when I set a breakpoint after executeUpdate, only the last row is inserted in the SQL table!

Comment: you need to create preparedStatement every time you want to insert into the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add preparedStatement.addBatch(); before you leave your loop.

And replace  preparedStatement.executeUpdate(); with preparedStatement.executeBatch();.

Answer (score 1):

You overide your parameters every time only the last executes. Use batch- Statement :
http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/

[Bulk insert in Java using prepared statements batch update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892105/bulk-insert-in-java-using-prepared-statements-batch-update)

Comment: I added the line preparedStatement.addBatch(); still the same problem.

Comment: had you add preparedStatement.executeBatch(); instead of     preparedStatement.executeUpdate(); ?